Midway arrow between each vertex
I looked at this question: TikZ: How to draw an arrow in the middle of the line?
And I'm still trying to make it work for my picture:
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \draw[<->] (0,1.1) node[above] {$y$} -- (0,0) -- (1.1,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[blue, fill=blue!10, domain=0:1, variable=\x]
  (0, 0)
  -- plot ({\x}, {\x^2})
  -- (1,1)
  -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

It's for showing Green's theorem and using arrows midway the parabola and midway the line segment so show the orientation of the curve.
How do I make arrows midway each vertex?

Something like this:

With use of the decorations.markings:
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                decorations.markings}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,
              > = Stealth,
->-/.style args = {#1/#2}{decoration={markings,                     
                        mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{>}},
                        mark=at position #2 with {\arrow{>}}
                        },
                    postaction={decorate}
                        }
                    ]
\draw[<->] (0,1.1) node[above] {$y$} -- (0,0) -- (1.1,0) node[right] {$x$};

\draw[->-=0.25/0.8, 
      blue, fill=blue!10, domain=0:1]
  (0, 0) --  plot (\x, \x^2)
         --  (1,1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Yes, that's basically it. Thanks.
I have some error when I try to put it into my document but I think I could work it out?

Hm, the best is to ask new question where you provide MWE derived from your document with my solution, which cause the same error as your document and show errors, which you get. Without this information is hard to help you. It may also happens that at prepare MWE you will find error yourself :-)
